# Using rel=value inside of getJson

Tags: jquery, getjson, rel

Let's say I have this script:

```
$('.myDiv').click(function(){
     $.getJSON('http://example.com/t.php', {
          department: 'department',
          manufacturer: ''
}
```

What is the correct syntax to have a parameter's[manufacturer] value be represented by something like this:

```
<div class="myDiv" rel="brand=myBrand">Hello World</div>
```

How can the value of the manufacturer parameter be defined by the relationship of the div?

Comment: Better use ID if it only one time. ("#myDiv").attr("rel") pass this eval. http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_eval.asp or else just use replace. To get only brand name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do

```
$('.myDiv').click(function(){
     $.getJSON('http://example.com/t.php', {
          department: 'department',
          manufacturer: $('div.myDiv').attr('rel')
}
```